# Check if function is density function

Tags: probability

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. $f(x)=\frac{a}{2}e^{-a|x|}$.
$a> 0$.  Check if $f$ if density function.

To me eye, it is sufficient to check two conditions:
(1) $f$ is non-negative on $\mathbb{R}$.
(2) $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

(1) is obviously fulfilled.
(2) $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{2}e^{-a|x|}dx = \frac{a}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|}dx=\frac{a}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|}dx$$
Is it ok approach ?  Is it easy to solve this integral ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check non-negativity and that $f$ integrates to $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{2}e^{-a|x|}dx 
&= \frac{a}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|}dx \\
&=\frac{a}{2}\left( \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{ax} \; dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \; dx \right) \\
&= \dfrac{a}{2} \left( \dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{a} \right) = 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for you clear answer!